# Do these sentences with “misunderstand” sound natural?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, grammaticality, verbs

​​There are some questions about how do I use "misunderstand", "misunderstanding" and "misunderstood" in English.

Are these sentence correct?

(I did something bad to someone)
"I'm so sorry! I misunderstand you"

(The man doesn't like the woman)
"If you don't like me, please don't kiss me. You will make misunderstand. (or cause me misunderstand) said the woman"

(Try to explain some to someone)
Please don't leave. I properly caused you misunderstanding.

does this sound natural?

Answer (score 1):

These sentences sound unnatural.

*misunderstand* means take something in the wrong sense, get a false feeling of understanding and actualy miss the true meaning or message.

See [this dictionary definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/misunderstand).

It is not the same as doing something "bad" (you can also cause harm by mistake with no misunderstanding, or intentionally with full understanding of what you are doing...)

The past tense and passive forms are both *misunderstood*. The gerund is *misunderstanding*.

The second sentence could be phrased in some other ways....

- "If you don't like me, please don't kiss me. I might misunderstand your feeling".
- "To avoid any misunderstanding, if you don't like me, please don't kiss me".

Finally, "I caused you misunderstanding" is formed as a double transitive verb (like "asked you a question"), but "cause" is not used this way. You could use "I caused you to misunderstand" instead, or perhaps more politely, "I created a misunderstanding".

Comment: Nice answer, **laugh**. I would like to add some notes to complement your answer: *Misunderstanding* is also a **Noun**, so it could be used in a place where a noun would be used:

I caused a *misunderstanding*;

There were a lot of *misunderstandings*.

Comment: In this context, _feelings_ is often used in the plural (i.e., I might misunderstand your **feelings**).